# numpy arrays in python for prediction model

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I've the following numpy arrays.

- X validation set, `X_val: (47151, 32, 32, 1)`
- y validation set (labels), `y_val_dummy: (47151, 5, 10)`
- y validation prediction set, `y_pred: (47151, 5, 10)`

When I run the code, it seems to take forever. Can someone suggest why? I  believe it's a code efficiency problem. I can't seem to complete the process.

```
y_pred_list = model.predict(X_val)
correct_preds = 0
# Iterate over sample dimension
for i in range(X_val.shape[0]):         
    pred_list_i = [y_pred_array[i] for y_pred in y_pred_array]
    val_list_i  = [y_val_dummy[i] for y_val in y_val_dummy]
    matching_preds = [pred.argmax(-1) == val.argmax(-1) for pred, val in zip(pred_list_i, val_list_i)]
    correct_preds = int(np.all(matching_preds))

total_acc = correct_preds / float(x_val.shape[0])
```